# Is there any way to learn more about SSL/TLS for iOS/MacOS development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, ssl, secure-transport

I am currently trying to make my own game app to have a secure transmission to my server. Specifically, I am trying to build a SSL/TLS layer over CF connections. There seems a decent support of this in iOS/MacOS (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/secure_transport/using_the_secure_socket_layer_for_network_communication). However, the resource of learning this library is pretty scarce.

By referencing some other posts online and guessing the usage of this secure API, I have built a simple program to (1) create a CFStream to my server and read/write it (2) add SSL Context/IO to this stream and (3) successfully(!?) SSLHandsake.

My server now is just a dummy one created by OpenSSL (like: openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -CAfile CA.pem -accept 44330 -www).

It takes me lots of effort to achieve this step and I am actually stuck to continue the development.

The main problem of mine is the API docuemnt is not helpful. For example, I expect calling the "SSLCopyDistinguishedNames(ctx, names)" on my client will get the list of CA authorized by my server but it turns out returning nothing (e.g., size of names is 0).

Is there any good tutorial or Apple support to know API like this? or any working example? Is there any way I can dump the information on these "SecXXXRef" class, like SecTrustRef?

Comment: Are you sure that you need client authentication?

Comment: Hey, I am actually not 100% sure so that is the reason I want to play with it.